# Unit Testing Swift, CoreLocation issue with info.plist

Tags: swift, unit-testing, core-location, xctest, info.plist

I am testing my project with XCode, which has a CLLocationManager that updates location. I have added the Privacy - always usage description in the test and project info.plist file(both).
But when I run the test here is the log :

```
This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data
```

Anyone has this issue or know how to fix it

Comment: what is your plist's target? does it also include the *test* Target?

Comment: No it didn't include the test Target.

So I did add the test Target for the plist. But still get the same log.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested through a dummy app and it solved the issue.

Only thing is I don't know why but when I request the always authorization with the CLLocationManager in the Test in the dummy app. It doesn't allow.